# Why the data folder is empty of file explorer in android monitor device?

Tags: android, android-studio

[some time prob like this (Nothing To show)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0hcYh.png)  I try to run my app through different devices like emulator Genymotion or Samsung. When I want to check my data in monitor device there is no data in the data folder and sometimes nothing is present in the file explorer. But the app is working properly like search update the data. I have no idea about rooting because I'm new here, please someone guide me if you know...

Comment: in a user binary device or the non-rooted device, those data/ folders are not accessible

Comment: you can access data>data folder in emulators and not in real device without rooting

Comment: but i cant access data folder in emulator, what i do with this yaar